# C# Website - Class representing an object in a database is giving me the error CS0246 in VS2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, vs-web-site-project

The exercise I'm working on comes provided with solutions and an almost complete project to work on. The issue arises when I make a class-level variable that will hold a Product object selected from a drop down list populated by the database file Halloween.mdf.

The Code: 
Order.aspx.cs(File giving me the error)

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;

public partial class Order : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private Product selectedProduct;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) ddlProducts.DataBind();
        selectedProduct = this.GetSelectedProduct();
        lblName.Text = selectedProduct.Name;
        lblShortDescription.Text = selectedProduct.ShortDescription;
        lblLongDescription.Text = selectedProduct.LongDescription;
        lblUnitPrice.Text = selectedProduct.UnitPrice.ToString("c") + " each";
        imgProduct.ImageUrl = "Images/Products/" + selectedProduct.ImageFile;
    }
    private Product GetSelectedProduct()
    {
        DataView productsTable = (DataView)SqlDataSource1.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments.Empty);
        productsTable.RowFilter = string.Format("ProductID = '{0}'", ddlProducts.SelectedValue);
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)productsTable[0];

        Product p = new Product();
        p.ProductID = row["ProductID"].ToString();
        p.Name = row["Name"].ToString();
        p.ShortDescription = row["ShortDescription"].ToString();
        p.LongDescription = row["LongDescription"].ToString();
        p.UnitPrice = (decimal)row["UnitPrice"];
        p.ImageFile = row["ImageFile"].ToString();
        return p;
    }
    protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            CartItemList cart = CartItemList.GetCart();
            CartItem cartItem = cart[selectedProduct.ProductID];
            if (cartItem == null)
            {
                cart.AddItem(selectedProduct, Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text));
            }
            else
            {
                cartItem.AddQuantity(Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text));
            }
            Response.Redirect("Cart.aspx");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting the error message "The type or namespace name 'Product' could not be found (Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

When I look at the solution project I can see that the class-level variable Product is defined in the Assembly App code.

I'm not sure what the issue is here and am having a hard time asking for help due to my confusion.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint : answer is contained in the error message (`Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`). You need to say **where** the `Product` class is defined.

Comment: Have you tried placing your cursor over Product and pressing Ctrl+. (period) to have it recommend a 'using' ?   If so, what did it suggest?

Comment: It has suggest the following:
1. Generate class Product in new file
2. Generate class product
3. Generate nested class product
4. Generate new type.

And two encapsulation suggestions.

Comment: `Product GetSelectedProduct()` is not a class, it's a method. But you try to initialize it as a variable `selectedProduct`. If `Product` is also a class somewhere else you need to provide the correct namespace.

Comment: So where do *you* think it should be finding the class `Product`? Does the exercise perhaps tell you to write that class, and you haven't done so yet?

Comment: The excercise says nothing about writing that class. When I look at the completed project the class product is defined in the App_Code.

Comment: Open the `Product` class, copy its namespace, add it to the using directives of your `Order` class. Done.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was trivial. The directory was wrong had to move the project outside of it's containing folder and this fixed all the issues. Thanks for the help all.